ActiveMQ Artemis 2.37.0 messages and New Relic
When browsing my ActiveMQ Artemis 2.37.0 messages from the web console I see a newrelic property. Any idea what this is about?
[{"newrelic":"eyJkIjp7ImFjIjoiMTIxMjEwMiIsInByIjoxLjQ3MTk0LCJ0","x-opt-delivery-time":1726171200241,"x-opt-jms-dest":0,"address":"scheduled","creationTime":1726168127157,"x-opt-jms-msg-type":3,"messageID":515,"priority":4,"userID":"ID:ID:eb421cec-9cfa-49b3-b730-cf95485863da:1:1:1-1",,"durable":true,"tracestate":"1212102@nr=0-0-1212102-398731796-08b44ca926d53eec-b3094d0d0d351a97,","traceparent":"00-3ea7d1cdf9df58945f523cf2acc6f21f","expiration":0,"to":"scheduled","contentType":"application/octet-stream","timestamp":1726168127157}]


The message contains the following properties (among others):

newrelic
traceparent
tracestate

Given this, I'd say something in your environment is using New Relic distributed tracing. These header names match those defined in the New Relic documentation.
ActiveMQ Artemis will not add these properties to your message(s), at least not by default. Someone might potentially have configured a plugin to add these properties and deployed it to your broker so that's worth investigating as well.

So you think something in my env is injecting NewRelic tag into the message?
It's not part of ActiveMQ Artemis software? Thx

I updated my answer to address your comment explicitly.
